# Ler numeros separados por virgulas

Tags: c, string, arquivo

Estou precisando do sexto valor impresso em um `arquivo.txt`. Tentei ler o arquivo e imprimir os seis primeiros na tela para verificar se estava dando certo, para depois gerar um arquivo com apenas o valor que preciso organizado, tendo em vista que preciso repetir esse processo para mais quatro mil arquivos, porém não estou conseguindo nem mesmo isso.

O arquivo `txt` que estou tentando ler é o seguinte:

```
0.00053714,0.00053714,-0.00061595,0.30794,-0.00061595,0.30794,1.0001,1,0.0050735
```

Segue abaixo o código que fiz:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *arquivo;
    int i=1;
    float a[6];
    char valor[80],*token, linha;

    arquivo = fopen("arquivo.txt","r");

    if (arquivo = fopen ("arquivo.txt", "r") == NULL)
    {
        printf ("Error opening file\n");

        getch();
    }

    fgets(valor, 80, arquivo);
    printf("STRING ----> %s\n", linha);
    token = strtok(valor,",");
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        token=strtok(NULL,",");

        if(token!=NULL)
        {
            a[i]=atoi(token);
            i++;
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<7;i++)
        printf("a[%d] = %f\n", i, a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Como você quer que fique a saída do programa?

Comment: Eu gostaria apenas de conseguir pegar esse sexto valor para depois imprimir o mesmo em um arquivo txt, pois conseguindo fazer em um, já possuo uma parte de código pronto para ler todos os arquivo, assim apenas adicionaria esse trecho ao mesmo.

Comment: Este `0.30794` seria o sexto valor?

Comment: Sim, esse mesmo.

Comment: Como exemplo, o conteúdo do seu arquivo seria este: `0.00053714,0.00053714,-0.00061595`, a saída que vc desejaria seria desta forma:  
`0.00053714` |
`0.00053714` |
`-0.00061595`  
separando os valores por virgula **,** isso?

Comment: Na verdade nem preciso dos outros, apenas do 0.30794, pois no final juntarei o sexto valor de cada arquivo para formar um único.

Comment: Túlio - eu sei que você aprendeu C  - e é importante aprender melhor - mas esse tipo de tarefas é melhor fazer em outras linguagens - que automatizam detalhes como abrir arquivos, alocar strings, cortar strings, etc. Um programa de uma linha em Python que faz o que você está perguntando é: `print (open("[nome_do_arquivo.txt]").read().split(",")[5])`  (acabou esse é o programa todo - grave num arquivo "programa.py" e rode com `python programa.py` . Para juntar os dados dos 4000 arquivos, um programa formatado e legível vai ter umas 10 linhas.

Comment: Na verdade @jsbueno , esse arquivo que estou lendo é resultado de um script em pyton, porém como já não programo a muito tempo, busquei a que sabia que era C, já que não tinha tempo hábil para aprender pyton. Obrigado pela dica, vou procurar material para estudar essa linguagem, pois parece bem mais prática olhando por esse aspecto.

Comment: Legal - qquer coisa, meu e-mail tá no perfil aqui. Ou faça a mesma pergunta para um porgrama em Python que o pessoal responde. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie um programa que te pergunta qual é a posição do valor (elemento) que você precisa, e busca este valor conforme a posição escolhida, ele também separa os valores por virgula "**,**" conforme sua necessidade expressada na pergunta.

Vamos ao exemplo, segue a baixo o exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE* file = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");

    char line[256];
    char * valor;
    char * valor_escolhido;

    int cont_elemento = 1, posicao_elemento;

    printf("Informe a possicao ° do valor, (exemplo 1, 2 ou 6): ");
    scanf("%d", &posicao_elemento);

    if (file == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    /*Faz a leitura do arquivo linha por linha.*/
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file))
    {
        /*Pega o primeiro elemento separado por uma virgula.*/
        valor = strtok(line,",");

        /*Obtem os outros elementos até o fim da linha.*/
        while (valor != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s\n",valor);
            valor = strtok(NULL, ",");

            cont_elemento++;

            if (cont_elemento == posicao_elemento)
                valor_escolhido = valor;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\nValor escolhido: %s\n\n", valor_escolhido);

    fclose(file);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Usei a função `strtok` que faz parte do header `string.h`, ela pode ser usada quando precisamos quebrar uma string em **C** usando um *delimitador*, assim ela retornara suas partes conforme o valor especificado no *delimitador* que neste caso é a virgula `,`. Veja a assinatura da função `strtok`:

```
char * strtok ( char * str, const char * delimiters );
```

**Explicação do programa.**

Eu assumi que a estrutura do seu arquivo esteja no seguinte formato conforme o conteúdo do mesmo que foi informado na pergunta, segue a estrutura do arquivo que serão os dados de entrada:

```
0.00053714,0.00053714,-0.00061595,0.30794,-0.00061595,0.30794,1.0001,1,0.0050735
```

O programa perguntara a posição do valor (elemento):

> Informe a possicao ° do valor, (exemplo 1, 2 ou 6):

Valor que informei:

> 6

Escolhi o 6° (sexto) elemento, e ele me retornara o valor `0.30794`.

**Saída do programa**.

Com base nos dados de entrada que foram informados para o programa no exemplo acima, o programa ira gerar a seguinte saída:

> 0.00053714
>   0.00053714
>   -0.00061595
>   0.30794
>   -0.00061595
>   0.30794
>   1.0001 1
>   0.0050735
>
> Valor escolhido: 0.30794

**Conclusão.**

Para obter o valor escolhido tiver que contar a quantidade de ocorrências emitida pela função `strtok` usando a variável `cont_elemento`, e fazer a validação para comparar com a posição escolhida em um `if`, veja: `if (cont_elemento == posicao_elemento)`, em seguida só atribuir a string com o valor separado pela função para a string `valor_escolhido`, assim obtive o valor escolhido.

Fontes:
[Split string in C every white space.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4513316/5429980)
[Split string into tokens.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/)
[Como usar a função strtok() para quebrar uma string C usando delimitadores.](http://www.arquivodecodigos.net/dicas/c-como-usar-a-funcao-strtok-para-quebrar-uma-string-c-usando-delimitadores-3189.html)

Comment: Perfeito e muito bem explicado. Muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: Bonito. poético. Mas lembrem-se, exceto para fins didáticos,não é o tipo de programa que você deve fazer em C.

Comment: @jsbueno não é uma solução completa tem que melhorar muita coisa neste programa, se tiver alguma sugestão de melhoria?

Comment: Eu não investiria nesse programa em C - como eu disse, linguagens de mais algo nível tem uma facilidade muito grande para lidar com strings, e leitura de arquivos - principalmente as linguagens dinâmicas. Eu sou bom (e fanático por) Python. Posso até escrever o programa em Python abaixo .

Comment: No seu programa, sem analizar muito a fundo, notei um problema de segurança/integridade que é típico de quando queremos fazer programas simples em C  - vocẽ deveria ter um teste por null logo depois da chamada `valor = strtok(NULL, ",");`  - e sair do `while`ali - e não usar esse valor caso ele seja NULL - e também uma inicialização da variável "valor_escolhido". Como está, se o arquivo lido tiver menos elementos que o esperado, você passa um ponteiro indefinido, ou NULL  para o printf.

Comment: @jsbueno fiz a solução conforme a necessidade do AP que era em C, porem eu também preferia usar uma linguagem de alto nível como Python, mais pela facilidade de manipulação de strings. Esse erro que vc citou eu não tinha percebido.

Comment: sim, eu entendo perfeitamente. Pergunta de C, resposta em C. Veja meu comentário na pergunta.  O ero que eu citei é um dos motivos, além de ficar mais curto, de fazer programas assim em linguagens de alto nível. Em C você tem que se preocupar com tudo, o tempo todo.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho , adaptei esse programa para meu caso, porém não consigo pegar o sexto valor dos 4000 arquivos. Por algum motivo, o fgets dentro do while esta dando segmentation fault. Consigo ler sempre até o arquivo 1016. Testei em outro computador e da mesma forma, ocorreu segmentation fault, porém no arquivo 1018. Acho que deveria ter que altear algum parâmetro para realizar várias vezes essa operação, porém não consegui ver qual especificamente. Você tem alguma ideia?

Comment: @TúlioAlves não sei para qual é a finalidade do algoritmo que vc já esta usando, se eu fosse você eu usaria uma linguagem mais alto nível para a manipulação de `strings`, ou faria outra pergunta para isolar o problema a respeito.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho obrigado, vou postar outra pergunta, fica mais fácil e organizado.

Answer (score 1):

**awk** é quase C

```
awk -F, '{print $6}' arquivo.txt
```

Explicação simplificada:
Internamente o awk divide cada linha em campos (neste caso o separador de campo é `,` devido ao `-F,`),
cada campo fica associado a um número `$1, $2, ...$n` basta-nos dizer o que 
queremos imprimir.

Comment: O que faz `awk -F`? fiquei curioso

Comment: @rray `-F, `  significa o separador de campo é `,`

Comment: Tipo um split por 6 caracteres?

Comment: @rray, mais ou menos: juntei um breve explicação.

Comment: Entendi agora :D